# Nuxt-mail not sending email when I use nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, nuxt.js, nodemailer

I have a Nuxtjs app running on my VPS in my Docker containers with nginx. I need to send form in email and I'm using nuxt-mail (lib for nuxt using nodemailer) for it. In dev it worked fine without nginx and domain, I sent forms directly on `IP.of.VPS/mail/send/` and it was ok.

Now in production when I'm trying to send mail I have CORS or preflight errors, depends on which address I'm trying to send. I tried a lot options: tried to send on http, https, tried using domain name and IP address of my VPS and it doesn't work.

**I have next nginx configs (part with conditions i took from this [website](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) trying to fix CORS errors):**

```
    server {
        listen      80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name studioagnc.com;
    
        location / {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
        }
    
        location /mail/send {
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }
        }
    
        location ^~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
            root  /data/letsencrypt/;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen      443           ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443           ssl http2;
        server_name               studioagnc.com;
    
        ssl                       on;
    
        add_header                Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
    
        ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout       10m;
    
        ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers               "ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;";
    
        ssl_stapling              on;
        ssl_stapling_verify       on;
        resolver                  8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
    
        ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/studioagnc.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/studioagnc.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/studioagnc.com/chain.pem;
    
        access_log                /dev/stdout;
        error_log                 /dev/stderr info;
        
        # other configs
        location / {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_redirect    off;
            proxy_pass         http://nuxt_app:3000;
        }
    
        location /mail/send/ {
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Part of my Nuxt component where I'm trying to send form:**

```
    submit() {
          this.$axios.$post("/mail/send", {
            from: "studioagnc_redirect@mail.ru",
            subject: "Заказ AGNC",
            html: `<h2 style='color:#9389d2; margin-bottom: 0.3em'>Имя заказчика:</h2>
            <p style='margin: 0 0'>${this.userName}</p>
            <h2 style='color:#9389d2; margin-bottom: 0.3em'>Почта заказчика:</h2>
            <p style='margin: 0 0'>${this.userMail}</p>
            <h2 style='color:#9389d2; margin-bottom: 0.3em'>Услуги: </h2>
            <ul>${String(
              this.value.map(el => {
                return `<li>${el.name}</li>` + "\n";
              })
            ).replaceAll(",", "")}</ul>
            <h2 style='color:#9389d2; margin-bottom: 0.3em'>Описание:</h2>
            <p style='margin: 0 0'>${this.userDetails}</p>`
          });
        }
```

**My `nuxt.config.js` file:**

```
    modules: [
        "@nuxtjs/axios",
        [
          "nuxt-mail",
          {
            message: {
              to: "studioagnc_redirect@mail.ru"
            },
            smtp: {
              host: "smtp.mail.ru",
              port: 465,
              secure: true,
              auth: {
                user: "studioagnc_redirect@mail.ru",
                pass: "secret_key"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
    
      axios: {
        baseURL: "https://195.140.147.103"
      }
```

Current console output:
[image: console output]
Network tab:
[image: network tab output]
Error detail:
[image: error detail]

If it's important IP of my VPS is `195.140.147.103` and domain is https://studioagnc.com/

What should I do in nginx configs to make it work properly?

Comment: Try instead either sending the request to `https://studioagnc.com/mail/send` (or whatever the domain is on your SSL certificate) or else use `http://195.140.147.103/mail/send` (http, not https)

Comment: @sideshowbarker when i'm trying to send to `https://studioagnc.com/mail/send` i have 500 error. And when i use `http://195.140.147.103/mail/send` for send it shows me `9ed4a54.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://studioagnc.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://195.140.147.103/mail/send'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` I think it's nginx configs problems.

Comment: i entered inside of nginx container and checked for nginx logs and it's empty. idk what to do and where to look to find out the problem(